# How to download a webpage(only text) to specific extention(eg .xml) by passing a URL

Tags: c#, xml

I have a URL, when pasted into Internet Explorer it generates a XML which then can be saved by right clicking and choosing save as "*.xml". How can I achieve this via code. I have seen many examples using webclient and but not working:

```
String page = "http://www.yoursite.net/index.html";
        HttpWebRequest site = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(page);
        HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)site.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        String data = read.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.WriteAllText("c:\\path\\to\\file.xml", data)` to write the contents to a file after obtaining the data from the stream.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx